# How to create dynamic schema using CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax

I need to insert a new column to a row to handle semi structured data using CQL. Is it possible ? If it is possible, please advise.

Comment: Are you trying to add a column once? Or to do this dynamically?

Comment: @phact - to add a column  dynamically..

Comment: As Alexander pointed out, adding columns dynamically is not best practice in cassandra. You must wait until a schema is fully propagated before issuing another statement. You are probably better off using one of the options Alexander suggests.

Comment: Otherwise you can use something like cluster.getMetadata().checkSchemaAgreement() in the java driver, but this is not the recommended route. Test thoroughly...Note that this will not work in a distributed client scenario.

Comment: thanks phact..can you confirm if we can create dynamic schema through Thrift API ..?

Comment: The thrift API is being deprecated, you should look into the cql options below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamically changing table structures is not advised in Cassandra as it involves all the nodes in the cluster to acknowledge the ALTER statement (among other issues you might have).

Your best options are :

- to use collections with basic types: a map could do the trick in your case
- to use a combo of collections and UDTs
- to use a text field and store your data in JSON for example (suitable if data isn't updated afterwards)
- to use a blob and store whatever format you want in it (given you never update it as well)

You could also change your model and handle the columns you want to add as rows instead.

If you want further advices, share your model and use case more precisely.